# Sentence case tool - Not all sentences start with capital letter

Tags: javascript

could you look at this code. I need to fix the Sentence Case option. The first letter of each sentence should be capitalized.

*e.g. This is test. This is test. This is test.*

The problem is that only the first sentence starts with a capital letter and other sentences do not.

https://github.com/freewarelovers/CaseConverter

---

```js
// LowerCase, Title And Sentence Case Converter Tool

var stringbox = document.getElementById('stringbox')
var wordcountspan = document.getElementById('wordcount')
var charcountspan = document.getElementById('charcount')

function convertstring(textarea, action) {
  if (action == 'sentencecase') {
    textarea.value = sentenceCase(textarea.value)
  } else if (action == 'titlecase') {
    textarea.value = toTitleCase(textarea.value)
  } else if (action == 'capitalcase') {
    textarea.value = CapitalCase(textarea.value)
  } else if (action == 'lowercase') {
    textarea.value = lowerCase(textarea.value)
  } else if (action == 'uppercase') {
    textarea.value = upperCase(textarea.value)
  }
  return false
}

function sentenceCase(str) {
  var str = str.toLowerCase().replace(/\si\s/g, ' I ');
  str = str.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + str.slice(1);
  return str
}

//reference: https://github.com/gouch/to-title-case
function toTitleCase(str) {
  var smallWords = /^(a|an|and|as|at|but|by|en|for|if|in|nor|of|on|or|per|the|to|vs?\.?|via)$/i;
  var str = str.toLowerCase()
  return str.replace(/[A-Za-z0-9\u00C0-\u00FF]+[^\s-]*/g, function(match, index, title) {
    if (index > 0 && index + match.length !== title.length &&
      match.search(smallWords) > -1 && title.charAt(index - 2) !== ":" &&
      (title.charAt(index + match.length) !== '-' || title.charAt(index - 1) === '-') &&
      title.charAt(index - 1).search(/[^\s-]/) < 0) {
      return match.toLowerCase();
    }

    if (match.substr(1).search(/[A-Z]|\../) > -1) {
      return match;
    }

    return match.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + match.substr(1);
  });
};

//reference: https://medium.freecodecamp.com/three-ways-to-title-case-a-sentence-in-javascript-676a9175eb27
function CapitalCase(str) {
  return str.toLowerCase().split(' ').map(function(word) {
    return (word.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + word.slice(1));
  }).join(' ');
}

function lowerCase(str) {
  return str.toLowerCase();
}

function upperCase(str) {
  return str.toUpperCase();
}

function wordandcharcount() {
  wordcountspan.innerHTML = stringbox.value.split(' ').length
  charcountspan.innerHTML = stringbox.value.length
}


stringbox.addEventListener('input', function() {
  wordandcharcount()
}, false)

wordandcharcount()
```

```html
<textarea id="stringbox"></textarea>
<span id="wordcount"></span>
<span id="charcount"></span>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please make it a [mcve] - for example how to execute your convertstring?

Comment: Also please to not tag spam. Neither PHP nor jQuery is relevant in your question

Answer (score 2):

I assume a sentence always begins at the start of the input string or immediately after a period.

```js
var text = "this is a test. this is a test. this is a test.";
text = text.replace(/(^|\.\s*)([a-z])/g, function(match,c1,c2,offset,str) {
    return c1 + c2.toUpperCase();
});
console.log(text)
```

This will output `This is a test. This is a test. This is a test.`

Comment: And if you target modern browsers, you don't have to assume all sentences start after a period: `'test word? test word։ test word؟'.replace(/(^|\p{Sentence_Terminal}\s*)([a-z])/gu, (match, c1, c2)  => c1 + c2.toUpperCase());`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to do it.

```
const sentence = "this is talha. i am 8. i am a boy. I like to play soccer";

//  convert to an array
const arr = sentence.split(".");

// capitalize first word for each sentence
let capitalized = arr.map((str, index) => {
  if (index === arr.length - 1) {
    str = str.trim().charAt(0).toUpperCase() + str.trim().slice(1);
    return (str += " ");
  }
  str = str.trim().charAt(0).toUpperCase() + str.trim().slice(1) + ".";
  return (str += " ");
});

// convert back to string and log
console.log(capitalized.join(""));
```